# How to wrap part of the text with spans using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dom, word-wrap, dom-traversal

Here is what I am trying to do

```
Fox<span>Rox</span>
```

before that

```
FoxRox
```

How do I wrap spans around `Rox`?

Comment: If you can tell us why do you need it and some more context we will able to help you more. Take is as an advise to further questions here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will search you whole DOM and replace each `Rox` with `<span>Rox</span>`:

```
$(':contains("Rox")').html(function(index, oldHTML) {
    return oldHTML.replace(/(Rox)/g, '<span>$&</span>');
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/FFBnj/3)

Comment: I got  Unexpected token ILLEGAL  too :(

Comment: @gdoron I'm getting some odd results - might be the fault of jsbin.

Comment: @gdoron Just tried everything in jsfiddle and it worked fine. Goodness, jsbin had me going crazy for a moment there.

Comment: @user1374078 It was jsFiddle error, it's blocking you from doing things. Now I disabled it with a container. Try again please

Answer (score 5):

In this case, you could use the JavaScript `replace()` method:

```
'FoxRox'.replace(/(Rox)/, '<span>$1</span>');
```

To replace this all through the document, you could try the following:

```
$(":contains('Rox')").html(function(i,o){
  return o.replace(/(Rox)/g, '<span>$1</span>');
});​
```

Note, if your term is not "Rox", you'll need to change it in the above script.

Comment: I guess the hard thing is how to change the DOM.

Comment: Please check my websites that I am working on right now, http://www.foxklld.site88.net. I pasted your code but it gives me some kind of error and also that I want to replace `KllD` with `Rox` you will see what I mean. So I want something like this `'FoxKllD'.replace(/(KllD)/, '<span>Rox</span>');`. Also, On chrome console it said  Unexpected token ILLEGAL.

Comment: @user1374078 But you want to replace it all throughout your document, right?

Comment: I dont know anything about it. As long as it works it's fine for me

Comment: @user1374078 I'm asking what you want. Do you want the script to search the entire website, and replace "K11D" where ever it is with `"<span>Rox</span>"`?

Comment: @user1374078. So I added the relevant tags to your question. Please do it next time to make your question clearer.